# Applying skin to VLC activex plugin to play RTSP source files in web pages

Tags: html, vlc, rtsp

I have been trying playing rtsp source files in my web page. I have googled it on net and found that adding `VLC activex plugin` can do the trick. i have used following code to achieve this and its working so far ..

```html
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
        codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
        width="640" height="480" id="vlc" events="True">
  <param name="Src" value="rtmp://192.168.0.102/vod/20141022_162503.mp4" />
  <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
  <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
  <param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />

</object>
```

Now I just want to improve the look and feel of the player. Is there is any way I can add some skin files to it or by some other way.

Comment: So you have issue with playing video or applying skin? Title and question are asking different things.

Comment: It was with skin only. i have updated my question title

Comment: I feel something important needs to be said. ActiveX isn't cross-browser supported. Neither is it supported across different operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Vlc Web Plugins has no skinnig capabilities. Absolutely.
So if you need something like this, you have following options:

1. Dig into Vlc Web Plugins sources and implement what you need (very long way);
2. Use Vlc Web Plugins with enabled windowless mode and create UI over plugin window with html (way with very poor perfomance, and not working with Vlc ActiveX);
3. Use FBVLC or WebChimera (in FBVLC compatibility mode) and enabled windowless mode, and create UI same way as in (2). Still will have poor perfomance, but at least it will work on IE;
4. Use WebChimera and write any UI you like wihout any perfomance penalties - this project was created exactly to solve this task;

If you want to know what WebChimera is - just google it, you will find it on the first page of seach output.

P.S.: WebChimera based on libvlc and supports Win/Mac/Linux platforms